# convert array of aclitem into multiple rows redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have one array with column values as

{james=UC/james,adam=C/james,chris=U*C*/james,john=U/james}

The above column values are not json. They are in string in the following form:

```
{ username=privilegestring/grantor }
```

How to convert above column into multiple rows

Comment: Is there a limit on how many possible permissions pairings there could be or can they be essentially infinite?

Comment: No limit on that. But I think max limit can be number of users created in redshift

Comment: Is there a small subset of known access privileges, or is any letter (possibly followed by an asterisk) a valid access privilege value?

Comment: no small subset i am quering on table pg_namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit #3:**
*Updated the query to specifically target pg_catalog.pg_namespace for acl permissions grants, via CTE **pg_catalog**. Currently this CTE is filtered in the where clause to select a single namespace name (`'avengers'`); if you want to select from multiple namespace names, you should be able to add them into the `WHERE` clause of this CTE directly, or in the case of wanting all namespace names, remove the clause altogether.*

*It's worth noting as well, that you will need to expand the case statements in `access_privilege_types` to handle all permissions cases: 'r', 'w', 'a', 'd', and 'x', for the operations: `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `REFERENCE`, respectively.*

**Edit #2:**
The final posted version of the query below should get you the data you want in the format that you want it in. I don't know how many possible values there are for the permissions types; if you have more than the two specified currently, you will need to expand the case statements in the CTE* `access_privilege_types`*. Obviously you'll also need to replace your table name within the query, etc.. Let me know if you run into any trouble and I'll help as necessary.

**Edit #1:**
Was able to validate that this query works in Redshift. Updated the query to break out separate rows by grantee and owner. The current version doesn't break out individual permissions by row yet -- Will take a look later tonight to see if I can get that working as well.

**Original:**
I don't have access to my Redshift cluster to test this at the moment, but I will when I get home. The general idea behind the following method, is to create a numbered index table to cross join against that will expand the data in the permissions field into a row-based representation.

I had inquired about the size limit, because this will currently only handle 10,000 possible delimited values, however you can adjust the CTEs to scale up to larger amounts if needed for your specific application:

**Revision 3 Query:**

```sql
        WITH

    pg_namespace AS (
        SELECT
            nspname
            , nspowner
            , rtrim(ltrim(array_to_string(nspacl, ','), '{'), '}') as nspacl
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace
        WHERE nspname = 'public'
    ),

    -- Generating a table with the numbers 1 - 10 in a single column.
    ten_numbers AS (
        SELECT
            1 AS num
            UNION SELECT 2
            UNION SELECT 3
            UNION SELECT 4
            UNION SELECT 5
            UNION SELECT 6
            UNION SELECT 7
            UNION SELECT 8
            UNION SELECT 9
            UNION SELECT 0
    ),

    -- Expands the values in ten_numbers to create a single column with the values 1 - 10,000.
    depivot_index AS (
        SELECT
            (1000 * t1.num) + (100 * t2.num) + (10 * t3.num) + t4.num AS gen_num
        FROM ten_numbers AS t1
            JOIN ten_numbers AS t2 ON 1 = 1
            JOIN ten_numbers AS t3 ON 1 = 1
            JOIN ten_numbers AS t4 ON 1 = 1
    ),

    -- Filters down generated_numbers to house only the numbers up to the maximum times that the delimiter appears.
    splitter AS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM depivot_index
        WHERE gen_num BETWEEN 1 AND (
            SELECT max(REGEXP_COUNT(nspacl, '\\,') + 1)
            FROM pg_namespace
            )
    ),

    -- Cross joins permissions_groups and splitter to populate all requests, delimited on ','.
    expanded_input AS (
        SELECT
            pg.nspname
            , pg.nspacl
            , trim(split_part(pg.nspacl, ',', s.gen_num)) AS raw_permissions_string
        FROM pg_namespace AS pg
            JOIN splitter AS s ON 1 = 1
        WHERE split_part(nspacl, ',', s.gen_num) <> ''
    ),

    -- Breaks out the owner and grantee fields into their own columns respectively.
    users_with_raw_permissions_data AS  (
        SELECT
            e.raw_permissions_string
            , e.nspname
            , trim(split_part(e.raw_permissions_string, '=', 1)) AS grantee
            , trim(split_part(trim(split_part(e.raw_permissions_string, '=', 2)), '/', 2)) AS owner
            , trim(split_part(trim(split_part(e.raw_permissions_string, '=', 2)), '/', 1)) AS raw_permissions_data

        FROM
        expanded_input e
    ),

    -- Mines privilege types from raw string data.
    access_privilege_types AS (
        SELECT
          u.nspname
          , u.owner
          , u.grantee
          ,CASE
            WHEN position('C*' IN u.raw_permissions_data) > 0 THEN 'C*'
            WHEN position('U*' IN u.raw_permissions_data) > 0 THEN 'U*'
            WHEN position('C' IN u.raw_permissions_data) > 0 THEN 'C'
            WHEN position('U' IN u.raw_permissions_data) > 0 THEN 'U'
            ELSE u.raw_permissions_data
          END AS first_access_privilege
          , CASE
            WHEN position('U*' IN u.raw_permissions_data) > 0 THEN 'U*'
            WHEN position('C*' IN u.raw_permissions_data) > 0 THEN 'C*'
            WHEN position('U' IN u.raw_permissions_data) > 0 THEN 'U'
            WHEN position('C' IN u.raw_permissions_data) > 0 THEN 'C'
             ELSE u.raw_permissions_data
          END AS second_access_privilege
        , first_access_privilege || ',' || second_access_privilege AS merged_access_privileges
        FROM users_with_raw_permissions_data u
    ),

    -- Cross joins access_privilge_types and splitter to populate all privilege_types, delimited on ','.
    expanded_access_privilege_types AS (
        SELECT
            a.nspname
            , a.owner
            , a.grantee
            , trim(split_part(a.merged_access_privileges, ',', s.gen_num)) AS access_privileges
        FROM access_privilege_types AS a
            JOIN splitter AS s ON 1 = 1
        WHERE split_part(a.merged_access_privileges, ',', s.gen_num) <> ''
        GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
    )
SELECT
    ea.nspname
    , ea.owner
    , ea.grantee
    , LEFT(ea.access_privileges, 1) AS access_privilege
    , CASE
        WHEN POSITION('*' IN ea.access_privileges) > 0 THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
      END AS is_grantable
FROM expanded_access_privilege_types ea
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

**Edit #4:**
Adding some clarification on how the `ten_numbers`, `depivot_index`, and `splitter` tables work to break apart the `pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspacl` field. The general overview, is that `ten_numbers` and `depivot_index are created purely to return tables with numbered rows to use as an index when joining in the`split_part`values of`nspacl`.

`ten_numbers` generates a table with a single column, containing the numbers 0-9:

```
-------
| num |
-------
|  0  |
-------
|  1  |
-------
| etc |
-------
|  9  |
-------
```

This table is then expanded to house the range 0-9999 during the CTE `depivot_index`:

```
-----------
| gen_num |
-----------
|    0    |
-----------
|    1    |
-----------
|    2    |
-----------
|   etc   |
-----------
|   9998  |
-----------
|   9999  |
-----------
```

`splitter` then narrows down the table to house only the numbers up to the maximum count of the specified delimiter within the `nspacl` field:

```
-------
| num |
-------
|  0  |
-------
|  1  |
-------
| etc |
-------
|  6  |
-------
```

The table returned by `splitter` is then used as the target of a `CROSS JOIN` via the join on `1 = 1` in CTE `expanded_input`. This ensures that each member returned by `split_part` will have its own row:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  nspname  |               nspacl              |  raw_permissions_string |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  avengers |  "{james=UC/james,adam=C/james}"  |      "james=UC/james"   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  avengers |  "{james=UC/james,adam=C/james}"  |       "adam=C/james"    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  avengers |                 etc.              |            etc.         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you john for the reply, actually this data is from select * from pg_catalog.pg_namespace;

Comment: It is throwing error ERROR:  function regexp_count(aclitem[], "unknown") does not exist

Comment: @dharmeshmehta I've updated the query to hit `pg_catalog.pg_namespace` directly. Because the column `nspacl` returns an array value (`aclitem[]`), you can't parse it as raw text. I've used `rtrim(ltrim(array_to_string(nspacl, ','), '{'), '}')` to convert the array into text and then remove the leading '{' and trailing '}'. Currently this query runs on my cluster without issue, directly as written.

Comment: thank you john that was great, very helpful please tell me just onw thing what ten_numbers and depivot_index does.

Comment: @dharmeshmehta `ten_numbers` is a created table with a single column consisting of the numbers 0 through 9. `depivot_index` expands `ten_numbers` into a created table with a single column of the numbers 0 through 9999. The goal of this table is to provide rows to join against in `splitter` to 'depivot', or expand the single row entries returned in `nspacl` into multiple rows based on how many entries there are in the array. I will update my answer to try to explain this a little better.